# Max Double Slice Sum codility O(1) space complexity fail performance test case

Tags: java, algorithm, max

I was trying figure out why the below solution failed for a single performance test case for the 'Max Double Slice Sum' problem in the codility website: https://codility.com/demo/take-sample-test/max_double_slice_sum

There is another solution O(n) space complexity which is easier to comprehend overhere: [Max double slice sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20660989/max-double-slice-sum). But i am just wondering why this O(1) solution doesn't work. Below is the actual code:

```
import java.util.*;

class Solution {
    public int solution(int[] A) {      
        long maxDS = 0;
        long maxDSE = 0;
        long maxS = A[1];

        for(int i=2; i<A.length-1; ++i){
            //end at i-index
            maxDSE = Math.max(maxDSE+A[i], maxS);            
            maxDS = Math.max(maxDS, maxDSE);            
            maxS = Math.max(A[i], maxS + A[i]);            
        }

        return (int)maxDS;
    }
}
```

The idea is simple as follow:

- The problem can be readdress as finding max(A[i]+A[i+1]+...+A[j]-A[m]); 1<=i<=m<=j<=n-2; while n = A.length; we call A[m] is missing element within the slice.
- maxS[i] will keep max slice which end at current index i; in other words, = max(A[t] + ... + A[i]); while t < i; so when i=1; maxS = A[1]; Note that in solution, we don't keep array but rather latest maxS at current index (See above code).
- maxDSE[i] is max of all double slice which end at i; in other words, = max(A[t]+A[t+1]+...+A[i]-A[m])--end at A[i]; maxDS is the final max of double slice sum which we try to find.

Now, we just use a for-loop from i=2; -> i=A.length-2; For each index i, we notice some findings:

1. If the missing element is A[i], then maxDSE[i] = maxS[i-1] (max sum of
   all slice which end at i-1 => or A[t] + ... + A[i] - A[i]);
2. If missing element is not A[i] -> so it must be somewhere from A[1]->A[i-1] -> maxDSE = maxDSE[i-1] + A[i]; such as A[t] + ... + A[i] - A[m] (not that A[i] must be last element) with t

   so maxDSE[i] = Math.max(maxDSE[i-1]+A[i], maxS[i-1]);
   maxDS = Math.max(maxDS, maxDSE); max amount all maxDSE;
   and maxS[i] = Math.max(A[i], maxS[i-1]+A[i]);

by that way, maxDS will be the final result.

But strange that, I was only able to get 92%; with one failed performance test case as shown here:

medium_range 
-1000, ..., 1000

WRONG ANSWER 
got 499499 expected 499500

Could anyone please enlighten me where is problem in my solution? Thanks!

Comment: Why `i<A.length-1` ?

Comment: Did you exclude `A[0]` on purpose?

Comment: Yes. the first and last element in input array doesn't matter because the double slice sum is defined as: 0 ≤ X < Y < Z < N, sum=A[X + 1] + A[X + 2] + ... + A[Y − 1] + A[Y + 1] + A[Y + 2] + ... + A[Z − 1]; which means exclude element A[X], A[Y],A[Z]. (or 1<=X+1; && Z-1 <= N-2)

Answer (score 5):

Ok, I found the error with my code. Seems that I forgot one corner cases. When calculate DSE[i], in cases A[i] is missing number, maxS should contain the case when array is empty. In other word,  maxS should be calculated as:
maxS[i] = Math.max(0, Math.max(A[i]+maxS[i-1], A[i])); while 0 is for case of empty subarray (end at i-th); Math.max(A[i]+maxS[i-1], A[i]) is max of all slice with at least one element (end at i-index). The complete code as follow:

```
import java.util.*;

class Solution {
    public int solution(int[] A) {      
        long maxDS = 0;
        long maxDSE = 0;
        long maxS = A[1];

        for(int i=2; i<A.length-1; ++i){                        
            maxDSE = Math.max(maxDSE+A[i], maxS);       
            maxDS = Math.max(maxDS, maxDSE);                                    
            maxS = Math.max(0, Math.max(A[i], maxS + A[i]));     
        }

        return (int)maxDS;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it normal that your code returns 0 for the following sequence: [0, -5, -20, -2, -100, 0] ? shouldn't it return -7 (-5 -20 -2 -(-20)) ?

Comment: @PedroBorges no, 0 is the minimal result, because the double slice can be X=0,Y=1,Z=2 then the result is 0 and 0 > -7. So 0 is the value of the greatest double slice.

Comment: You don't need `maxS = Math.max(0, Math.max(A[i], maxS + A[i]));`. Version with `maxS = Math.max(0, maxS + A[i]);` also gets 100/100.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that for the input [-11, -53, -4, 38, 76, 80], your solution doesn't work. Yes, it tricks all the codility test cases, but I managed to trick all codility test cases for other problems too.

If you don't just want to trick codility, but also you want to come with a good solution, I suggest that you create a loop and a large number of random test cases (in number of elements and element values), and create a test method of your own, that you are sure works (even if the complexity is quadratic), compare the results from both methods and then analyze the current random input that doesn't fit.

Answer (score 1):

Here is clear solution. Best approach is to use algorithm of Kanade O(N) and O(1) by space

```
public class DuplicateDetermineAlgorithm {
    public static boolean isContainsDuplicate(int[] array) {
        if (array == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Input array can not be null");
        }
        if (array.length < 2) {
            return false;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            int pointer = convertToPositive(array[i]) - 1;
            if (array[pointer] > 0) {
                array[pointer] = changeSign(array[pointer]);
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private static int convertToPositive(int value) {
        return value < 0 ? changeSign(value) : value;
    }

    private static int changeSign(int value) {
        return -1 * value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have coded it in vb.net and got 100/100 getting idea form [solution by Guillermo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20660989/max-double-slice-sum)

```
Private Function solution(A As Integer()) As Integer
    ' write your code in VB.NET 4.0
    Dim Slice1() As Integer = Ending(A)
        Dim slice2() As Integer = Starting(A)
        Dim maxSUM As Integer = 0
        For i As Integer = 1 To A.Length - 2
            maxSUM = Math.Max(maxSUM, Slice1(i - 1) + slice2(i + 1))
        Next
        Return maxSUM
End Function
    Public Shared Function Ending(input() As Integer) As Integer()
        Dim result As Integer() = New Integer(input.Length - 1) {}
        result(0) = InlineAssignHelper(result(input.Length - 1), 0)
        For i As Integer = 1 To input.Length - 2
            result(i) = Math.Max(0, result(i - 1) + input(i))
        Next
        Return result
    End Function
    Public Shared Function Starting(input() As Integer) As Integer()
        Dim result As Integer() = New Integer(input.Length - 1) {}
        result(0) = InlineAssignHelper(result(input.Length - 1), 0)
        For i As Integer = input.Length - 2 To 1 Step -1
            result(i) = Math.Max(0, result(i + 1) + input(i))
        Next
        Return result
    End Function
        Private Shared Function InlineAssignHelper(Of T)(ByRef target As T, value As T) As T
            target = value
            Return value
        End Function
```

[Visit Codility to see the results](https://codility.com/demo/results/demoGXQU6K-2HU/)