# Find the maximal sum of any double slice

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity

I'm trying to solve a problem from the Codility that I already have a solution. The problem description is provided below,

```
A non-empty array A consisting of N integers is given.

A triplet (X, Y, Z), such that 0 ≤ X < Y < Z < N, is called a double slice.

The sum of double slice (X, Y, Z) is the total of A[X + 1] + A[X + 2] + ... + A[Y − 1] + A[Y + 1] + A[Y + 2] + ... + A[Z − 1].

For example, array A such that:

    A[0] = 3
    A[1] = 2
    A[2] = 6
    A[3] = -1
    A[4] = 4
    A[5] = 5
    A[6] = -1
    A[7] = 2
contains the following example double slices:

double slice (0, 3, 6), sum is 2 + 6 + 4 + 5 = 17,
double slice (0, 3, 7), sum is 2 + 6 + 4 + 5 − 1 = 16,
double slice (3, 4, 5), sum is 0.
The goal is to find the maximal sum of any double slice.

Write a function:

class Solution { public int solution(int[] A); }

that, given a non-empty array A consisting of N integers, returns the maximal sum of any double slice.

For example, given:

    A[0] = 3
    A[1] = 2
    A[2] = 6
    A[3] = -1
    A[4] = 4
    A[5] = 5
    A[6] = -1
    A[7] = 2
the function should return 17, because no double slice of array A has a sum of greater than 17.

Assume that:

N is an integer within the range [3..100,000];
each element of array A is an integer within the range [−10,000..10,000].
Complexity:

expected worst-case time complexity is O(N);
expected worst-case space complexity is O(N) (not counting the storage required for input arguments)
```

The solution is provided below,

```
public static int solution(int[] A) {

        int max = 0;

        int N = A.length;

        int[] A1 = new int[N];
        int[] A2 = new int[N];

        for (int i = 1; i < N - 1; i++) {
            A1[i] = Math.max(A1[i - 1] + A[i], 0);
        }

        for (int i = N - 2; i >= 1; i--) {
            A2[i] = Math.max(A2[i + 1] + A[i], 0);
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < N - 1; i++) {
            max = Math.max(max, A1[i - 1] + A2[i + 1]);
        }

        return max;
    }
```

I understand what was done in the initial 2 loops, however, the intention was not clear. My thoughts get disjointed at the time I approached the last for loop. Anyone kindly please explain the solution to me briefly?

Comment: What do you not understand? sum of double slice (x, y, z) is the sum of the sub array `[x + 1, y -1] + [y + 1, z - 1]`. `A1[i - 1]` is the maximum sub array on the left of index `i` and `A2[i + 1]` is the maximum sub array on the right of index `i`.

Comment: Maybe the answer here helps you already: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32042916/371191 It's basically the same code, but with better variable names.

Comment: @PhamTrung what are the 3 slice points then for the `i=1` in the last loop that has value of 14?

Comment: @SillyFreak Thanks for the code it looks better. How do you define the 3 slice points in the last loop?

Comment: Do you need to define? Or you just need the largest? Do you really understand what the first two loops do? I suggest you walk the code through a debugger to get an idea.

Comment: @PhamTrung OP said "I understand what was done in the initial 2 loops, however, the intention was not clear." A debugger will not help understand the intention of code. Anyway, now that I'm fairly certain what Arefe's problem is, I've written an answer.

Comment: @PhamTrung I didn't understand what the initial two loops are doing and clearly mentioned in the question.  Let's tune down a little, especially, when we come to offer the service voluntarily.

Comment: You mentioned `I understand what was done in the initial 2 loops ...`, if you don't understand, just said, `I don't clearly understand what was done in the ...`. I ask for a clarification whether you really understand as you mentioned, and suggest to walk through the debugger to really understand that part, what is the problem with that suggestion?

Comment: @SillyFreak Rather than giving the intention straight away to the OP, I think it is better to let him figure out by himself by a list of step which he can easily apply for his next problem. Yes, you cannot get the intention straight out of the debugger, but seeing the value in the array could help you closer rather than staring at the code.

Comment: @PhamTrung this is what I meant by tone down :) Anyways, take care.

Comment: Cool, take care :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will base my explanation on the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20660989/max-double-slice-sum/32042916#32042916), as it uses clearer variable names. Other than that, it's basically the same code as in your question:

```
class Solution {
    public int solution(int[] A) {        
        int[] maxStartingHere = new int[A.length];
        int[] maxEndingHere = new int[A.length];
        int maxSum = 0, len = A.length;

        for(int i = len - 2; i > 0; --i ) {            
            maxSum = Math.max(0, A[i] + maxSum);
            maxStartingHere[i] = maxSum;
        }
        maxSum = 0;
        for(int i = 1; i < len - 1; ++i ) {            
            maxSum = Math.max(0, A[i] + maxSum);
            maxEndingHere[i] = maxSum;
        }
        int maxDoubleSlice = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < len - 2; ++i) {
            maxDoubleSlice = Math.max(maxDoubleSlice, maxEndingHere[i] + maxStartingHere[i+2]);
        }

        return maxDoubleSlice;

    }
}
```

The key here is that the code does not look for the maximum slice, only for its sum. The array `maxStartingHere` records at index `i` what maximum sum you'd reach if you combine contiguous items starting at `i+1`; `maxEndingHere` does the same in reverse. Let's look at an example for that:

```
i:             0  1  2  3  4
A:             1 -3  2 -1  ...
maxEndingHere: 0  1  0  2  1
```

Note that:

- `i=0`: there are no elements left of `i`, so the sum is 0.
- `i=2`: Taking `A[0..1]` is suboptimal, so the maximum of `0` is achieved by not summing anything at all.
- `i=4`: Another negative element, but `2 + -1` is still better than `0`. We're not considering `1 + -3 + 2 + -1` because we already know that the maximum we can reach left of the `2` is negative.

I hope you see that this array shows what can be achieved by choosing different `X`, but the concrete choice of `X` is not recorded - just its consequence. Every `i` corresponds to a `Y`, and `maxEndingHere[i-1]` corresponds to the consequence of choosing `X` optimally for a particular `Y`.

So we know what sums choosing `X` and `Z` optimally, for a particular `Y`, result in. That means it only remains to choose the best `Y` (or more precisely: the sum resulting from the best `Y`). And that is what happens in the third loop.

To reiterate:

- What is the maximum you can get, ending anywhere, when starting from a particular item? That's `maxStartingHere`.
- What is the maximum you can get, starting anywhere, when ending at a particular item? That's `maxEndingHere`.
- What is the maximum you can get when ending/starting at a particular item? That's `maxDoubleSlice`.

Comment: Hello, thank you so much for the explanation.  I may not be able to get the solution without so comprehensive explanation. Add a note: `the maximum slice value between A[0] (excl.) and A[i] (incl.) contains in maxEndingHere[i] and the maximum slice value between A[N-1] (excl.) and A[i] (incl.) contains in maxStartingHere[i]` and `point Y in the double slice of [X, Y, Z]  is indicated by the (i+1) index of A in last loop`. 
 This explains  `it remains to choose the best Y (or more precisely: the sum resulting from the best Y). And that is what happens in the third loop.`